# Dual norms: equivalent definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $\|\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The dual norm of $\|\|$, denoted $\|\|^*$, is defined as
$\|v\|^*=\text{sup}(v^{\top}x : \|x\|<= 1)$.

I want to show that the inequality in the constraint can be replaced with an equality, i.e., that the supremum is achieved at the boundary of the feasible set. For that, I want to show that $v^{\top}x$ is increasing in $\|x\|$, i.e.,
$\|x_{1}\|>\|x_{2}\|$ implies $v^{\top}x_{1}>v^{\top}x_{2}$.

This seems intuitively clear but how can I show this using just the properties of a norm?

Comment: Let $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ then $|v^T x| = |v^T y|\ \|x\|$

Comment: But why is it true that if $\|x_{1}\|>\|x_{2}\|$ then $|v^{\top}y_{1}|>|v^{\top}y_{2}|$?

Comment: It is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, but how does the normalization trick help then?

Comment: $\|y\|=1{}{}{}$

Comment: How will $\|x_{1}\|>\|x_{2}\|$ imply $|v^{\top}y_{1}|\|x_{1}\|>|v^{\top}y_{2}|\|x_{2}\| $ unless $|v^{\top}y_{1}|>=|v^{\top}y_{2}|$?

Comment: Come on... $$\sup_{\|y\| = 1} |v^T y| =\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \frac{|v^T x|}{ \|x\|} =  \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |v^T x|$$

Comment: Got it :) thanks